# How to locate the formatting of a line in the Options/Fonts and Colors dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts, colors, resharper, resharper-6.0

I am using Resharper 6.x with VS2010.  One of the features is that if you double click on a variable, it is highlighted and then other usages of the variable are highlighted, like so:

[image]

The background and foreground colors of the highlighted variable are too close to each other and I am trying to change it in the Options/Fonts and Colors dialog.  It has a small Sample window (below).  I've gone through the entire list of display items and can't find the one matching what I see in the coding window.

[image]

So 2 questions:

1. Which display item should I change to affect the back/fore colors of the highlighted variables?
2. Is there some tool that that will point me to the display item in question for any piece of code?

P.S. I am using the [Ragnarok](http://winterdom.com/2007/10/ragnarokavs2005colorscheme) as my base color theme.

P.P.S.  This may have nothing to do with Resharper.  I turned it off and the coloring was still there.  I guess my original question still stands - how to affect the colors of the highlighted variables.

Comment: You don't need to double-click for highlighting. Just place cursor on symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Visual Studio 2010 Reference Highlighting

As you already presumed: The reference highlighting of current selection is not a ReSharper feature but a ***VS 2010*** feature. So you need to look at VS items in *Fonts and Colors* dialog.
The right display item is ***Highlighted Reference***.

[image]

## ReSharper Reference Highlighting

ReSharper's equivalent is *Highlight usages in file* by pressing ***Shift+Alt+F11***.

- Then all read references have light blue background color (related display item in *Fonts and Colors* dialog is ***ReSharper Read Usage***).
- And all write references have rose background color (related display item in *Fonts and Colors* dialog is ***ReSharper Write Usage***).

But the disadvantage of ReSharper's reference highlighting is that you need to press a shortcut. VS does the highlighting automatically.